# Adjustment of selecInputs simultaneously on shiny

Tags: r, shiny

How to adjust my third `selectInput`, `destination`, since if I choose a departure point, for example, `Market 1`, in the second `selectInput`, in the third `selecInput`, which refers to my destination point, `Market 1` keeps appearing . In this case, it would not have to appear, only the other Markets.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(lubridate)


df1<- structure(
  list(
    Marketname = c("Market1","Market1", "Market2","Market2", "Market3", "Market3"),
    Days = c("Sunday","Sunday","Sunday","Sunday", "Sunday","Tuesday"),
    Openinghours = c("Morning","Evening", "Morning","Evening","Evening","Evening")
  ), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")


ui <- fluidPage(  
  shiny::navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
                    br(),
                    tabPanel("",
                             sidebarLayout(
                               sidebarPanel(
                                 dateInput("date", "Which day shift do you choose?"),
                                 selectInput("hours", label = h5("Which work shift do you choose??"), choices = NULL, 
                                             selected = ""),
                                 selectInput("departurepto", label = h5("Departure point"), choices = NULL, 
                                             selected = ""),
                                 
                                 selectInput("destination", label = h5("Destination point"), choices = NULL, 
                                             selected = ""),
                                 
                                 ),
                               mainPanel(
                               )
                             ))
  ))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  week_day <- reactive({
    wday(input$date, label = TRUE, abbr = FALSE)
  })
  
  observe({
    updateSelectInput(session, "hours",
                      choices = unique(df1[df1$Days == week_day(), "Openinghours"])
    )
  })
  
  observe({
    updateSelectInput(session, "departurepto",
                      choices = unique(df1[df1$Days == week_day() & df1$Openinghours %in% input$hours, "Marketname"])
    )
  })
  
  observe({
    updateSelectInput(session, "destination",
                      choices = unique(df1[df1$Days == week_day() & df1$Openinghours %in% input$hours, "Marketname"])
    )
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: you just need to pass ```input$departurepto``` to the ```selected``` arg in ```updateSelectInput ``` function:   ```updateSelectInput(session, "destination", choices = unique(df1[df1$Days == week_day() & df1$Openinghours %in% input$hours, "Marketname"], selected = input$departurepto))```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @asaei! I tried the way you said,  but even so, Market1 appears, for example, at the departure point and the destination point. Did yours work?

Comment: Sorry I did not read your question properly. I see what you mean now. I will answer it below in the answer section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `setdiff` to exclude departure from the destination options:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(lubridate)


df1<- structure(
  list(
    Marketname = c("Market1","Market1", "Market2","Market2", "Market3", "Market3"),
    Days = c("Sunday","Sunday","Sunday","Sunday", "Sunday","Tuesday"),
    Openinghours = c("Morning","Evening", "Morning","Evening","Evening","Evening")
  ), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")


ui <- fluidPage(  
  shiny::navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
                    br(),
                    tabPanel("",
                             sidebarLayout(
                               sidebarPanel(
                                 dateInput("date", "Which day shift do you choose?"),
                                 selectInput("hours", label = h5("Which work shift do you choose??"), choices = NULL, 
                                             selected = ""),
                                 selectInput("departurepto", label = h5("Departure point"), choices = NULL, 
                                             selected = ""),
                                 
                                 selectInput("destination", label = h5("Destination point"), choices = NULL, 
                                             selected = ""),
                                 
                               ),
                               mainPanel(
                               )
                             ))
  ))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  week_day <- reactive({
    wday(input$date, label = TRUE, abbr = FALSE)
  })
  
  observe({
    updateSelectInput(session, "hours",
                      choices = unique(df1[df1$Days == week_day(), "Openinghours"])
    )
  })
  
  observe({
    updateSelectInput(session, "departurepto",
                      choices = unique(df1[df1$Days == week_day() & df1$Openinghours %in% input$hours, "Marketname"])
    )
  })
  
  observe({
    choices = unique(df1[df1$Days == week_day() & df1$Openinghours %in% input$hours, "Marketname"])
    updateSelectInput(session, "destination",
                      choices = setdiff(choices, input$departurepto)
    )
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Hi @asaei would you be able to resolve this issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75390637/adjust-selectinput-in-a-shiny-code-considering-two-dataframes it is similar